# How can I find out remotely when a Windows XP machine was last started?

Tags: windows-xp, boot

I have a machine running Windows XP Professional on my home network. I am an administrator on that machine. In order to find out when it was last started, I would normally walk over, start Process Explorer and look at the start time of a system process such as smss.exe.

However, I was wondering how I could do this remotely from my main PC (running Windows 7 Ultimate) on the same network.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In PowerShell:

```
gwmi -ComputerName computerName win32_operatingsystem | ft -a CSName,LastBootUpTime
```

The date time format of WMI is yyyyMMddhhmmss.hhhhh: ISO format without the separators.

Note multiple computers can be queried: use a common separated list of names.